# I am a non zero number

Tags: riddle, english

I am a non zero number.

I can be shown with a single letter, or three letters, or five letters or six letters.

What number am I?

Comment: Reading the accepted answer, it is language specific, since it would not work the same way in another language. Why is there NO Language Tag?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just an alternative for the jury to consider

> 12

One letter

> C as a hexadecimal

Three letters

> XII - Roman numerals often seen on timepieces

Five letters

> Dozen

Six letters

> Twelve

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Was the missing language tag meant to make finding the language part of the puzzle? Because the last two (five and six letters) are language specific...

Answer (score 21):

I think the answer is

> 1

One letter

> I (Roman numeral)

Three letters

> One

Five letters

> Unity

Six letters

> Single